# How can I insert directly an statement sql?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Well, a have a string contains 
`INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'Person1');`

How can I insert directly on Android SQLite without using ContentValues and SQLiteDatabase.insert()?

Answer (score 2):

The Android documentation encourages to use the query, insert, delete and update methods, but for more complex operations, it is possible to use a custom SQL statement:

- for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations you can use SQLiteDatabase.execSql(String sql).
- for SELECT operation you can use rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs).

See [SQLiteDatabase Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) for more details.

Comment: I try use SQLiteDatabase.execSql() but doesn't work.. public void execSQL (String sql, Object[] bindArgs)
Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. Doesn't work for insert, right? I have bad english =/

Comment: The `execSql` is not *intended* to be used for inserting, but it will work. The only problem is that you have to format the INSERT statement yourself.

Comment: The `execSql` works for inserting but it is not recommended since this method does not have return value. Then you can't retrieve the number of affected rows in this operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using rawQuery() -

```
database.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
```